# How to make my sty file work only inside a environment?

Tags: macros, environments

Say for example, i have a `bibpattern.sty` which consists of some latex commands (like `\COMMENT`).
I want this `bibpattern.sty` to work only inside `\begin{thebibliography} ... \end{bibliography}`.

The same `\COMMENT` can be found outside `\begin{thebibliography} ... \end{bibliography}`, but it has different work to do.

Below is my Sample Code

```
\documentclass{article}

%\newcommand\COMMENT[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}
{
 \newcommand\COMMENT[1]{\textsc{#1}}
}

\begin{document}

Hi Hello this is %\COMMENT{Sample 2}


\begin{thebibliography}{00}
\renewcommand\COMMENT[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\bibitem{1}
This is a \COMMENT{Sample File}

\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

My problem is that, i want the `\COMMENT` to work only inside the `{thebibliography}` environment, the `\COMMENT` outside the `{thebibliography}` environment may have different purpose.

Comment: This seems confusing. Simplest solution would be to use different names like `\COMMENTA` and \COMMENTB`. But i think you can `\def` it inside the `thebibliography`-environment.

Comment: Or simply `\renewcommand\COMMENT[1]{\textsc{#1}}` inside the `thebibliography`-environment.

Comment: @Johannes, Actually i have a STY file, whatever definitions inside that STY file, should work only inside {thebibliography} environment only, is it possible? i am new to Latex

Comment: You can simply `\renewcommand\COMMENT[1]{\textsc{#1}}` inside the `thebibliography`-environment.

Comment: Seems my last comment got lost. `\RequirePackage{etoolbox}\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{
  \renewcommand\COMMENT[1]{\textsc{#1}}
}`

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for your prompt reply, it works very well, but possibility is I may or may not have \COMMENT in the rest of the bibliography environment, in that case, it is showing error if i use renew command for \COMMENT, please guide me how to solve this

Comment: @user52124: As long as there is `\COMMENT` already defined, a call to `\renewcommand{\COMMENT` is always possible. What is your precise issue now? Redefining it again inside the `thebibliography` environment?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, \COMMENT may or may not be defined intitally, that is the problem

Comment: @user52124: I posted a possible solution

Comment: I am voting to keep this question open, but it does need clarification and I would urge those involve to discuss it on chat.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: I voted (I think, I was the first one) for close, since there has been no effort for days now from the OP to answer or to clearify.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check whether the command `\COMMENT` is already available and if so, redefine (`\renewcommand`) or define `\newcommand`, **both** outside of `thebibliography` **and** inside of it, for the other usage of it. This can be achievied with `\ifdef{command_name}{true}{false}` command.

(I used blue color, to indicate the different command usages, which output comes from which environment)

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xcolor}


\RequirePackage{etoolbox}


%%%% Outer check --> for usage outside of bibliography
\ifdef{\COMMENT}{%
\renewcommand{\COMMENT}[1]{\textbf{#1}}%
}%
{% No, no comment command before
\newcommand{\COMMENT}[1]{\textbf{#1}}%
}%




\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}
{%
% Inner check and redefinition, if necessary
\ifdef{\COMMENT}{%
\renewcommand\COMMENT[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\textsc{#1}}}
}{% No, \COMMENT was not defined before 
\newcommand{\COMMENT[1]}{\textcolor{blue}{\textsc{#1}}}%
}%
}%


\begin{document}

Hi Hello this is \COMMENT{Sample 2}


\begin{thebibliography}{00}
\bibitem{1}
This is a \COMMENT{Sample File}
\bibitem{2}
This is another \COMMENT{comment inside bibliography}

\end{thebibliography}

And outside again: \COMMENT{Sample 3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it works like Charm, but now another problem arises, I can't define \COMMENT outside {thebibliography}, \COMMENT may or may not be defined by some unknown editors, i am not supposed to touch their definiton, only thing i can do is to use to own \COMMENT inside the {thebibliography} enviroment, Is this Possible??

Comment: @user52124: Of course this is possible, just comment (;-)) out the outside definition of `\COMMENT`, but this would mean, that you can't use `\COMMENT` outside of course as long it is not provided by other users/editors

Comment: @ Christian Hupfer lol, but i want their definition to stay alive anyways, i am not supposed to edit their Definitions, any other way to achieve this??? problem is that \COMMENT may even found inside some other STY files :-(

Comment: @user52124: I meant to comment out the definition in my solution, not the definition by others ;-) You could also remove my outside definition in you file (but not from my posted answer, of course ;-))

Comment: if \COMMENT is the only thing to change means i can do it manually, but i have 100 Definitions like that to do, so i thought of fixing this in Template, rather than a file :-(, Hoping the problem can be solved

Comment: @user52124: 100 definitions? What are your plans? :-)

Comment: @ Christian Hupfer any other ideas to solve this??

Comment: @user52124: I should see more of your 'surrounding' file and the definitions you want to make

Comment: say for example, you have some STY file which has a Definition \COMMENT used in {algorithmic} environment and also in bibliography environment, i am not supposed to change anything in algorthmic environment, but i should avoid that affecting inside my bibliography environment

Comment: @user52124: That is exactly what my solution does. It is inside a group (an environment!) and the `renewcommand` does not effect outside code. However, you can not do a `renewcommand` if the command does not already exist, regardless inside or outside. I have at the moment no other clue as doing the hard way, check which command already exists and if necessary, redefine it to fit your needs. This is basically the way an author of a package or class file has to go

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I would have posted (almost) the same solution now. But i used \ifcsundef{COMMENT}{%
 \providecommand{\COMMENT}[1]{#1}%
}{}` right in front of `\AtBeginEnv`.

@OP Reading all the comments above, i really don't know what it is you are trying to achieve in the long run. If you describe your problem a bit further, maybe in a new question, we could find a more general or *best-practice* solution.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Yes, `\using` \ifcsundef` would also work, true. And I am glad, that it's not only me that does not understand what the OP really wants to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for the Delay, i was out of town, @ChristianHupfer, and johannes_B, I thought i was clear in explaining my problem, anyways i will repeat it, i customized the bibliography part to my own commands, say for example (\ATITLE, \BTITLE etc), my fear is some author may use the same command name in the file somewhere, which will be given to me, so what i thought is, to make my Customized commands work inside bibliography only, without caring about the author Definition inside the file, or inside other sty files, I hope you understand this time

Comment: @user52124: Well, you want to redefine a lot of commands--> that's been understood. But who are the other authors? You want to introduce a different style of bibliography, that is possible, throught `.bst` files, but this mixing of your style and other authors' style is complicated and somewhat 'weird'. If you are the single other of the document, there is basically nothing to take care of